# Загрузка AssetBundle с хостинга в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Необходимо загрузить AssetBundle с хостинга. Написал такой код для загрузки с сервера:

```
        string bundleURL =
           "ftp://my_nick@files.000webhost.com/public_html/cub.unity3d"

        ...

        while (!Caching.ready)
            yield return null;

        var request = UnityWebRequestAssetBundle.GetAssetBundle(bundleURL);

        yield return request.SendWebRequest();

        if (!request.isHttpError && !request.isNetworkError)
        {
            model = DownloadHandlerAssetBundle.GetContent(request);
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.LogErrorFormat("error request [{0}, {1}]", bundleURL, request.error);

            model = null;
        }

        request.Dispose();
```

И при попытке выполнить данный код выдает ошибку: **error request [*адрес AssetBundle*, Login failed]**
Понимаю, что нужно присоединяться по логину и паролю, но как это сделать в коде - не знаю. Искал в документации, да и просто в интернете - ничего не нашел подходящего. При этом когда в первый раз напрямую в браузер вбил ссылку на бандл, выпала форма для ввода логина и пароля. В следующие разы этой формы уже не было, сразу качался файл.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[ftp://ЛОГИН:ПАРОЛЬ@files.000webhost.com/public_html/cub.unity3d](ftp://%D0%9B%D0%9E%D0%93%D0%98%D0%9D:%D0%9F%D0%90%D0%A0%D0%9E%D0%9B%D0%AC@files.000webhost.com/public_html/cub.unity3d), также учтите, что на сервере должен быть открыт доступ к файлу, для этого пользователя.